# Modal Layout not Responsive in Angular

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, pspdfkit

I work with angular7 , bootstrap4 and I use PSPDFKit in order to open pdf file in viewer

the viewer is open in the modal.

[image]

**the problem that the modal is not responsive.**

[image]

also I want that the pspdfkit to be open in all size of the modal ( 100 % of the size of the modal )

this is the html code :

```
<style>
  #app {
  
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
</style>





<div class="modal-dialog modal-800" >
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">attachmnt</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="bsModalRef.hide()">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div id="app">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button *ngIf="this.categAttachmnt !=null" type="button" class="btn btn-default"  (click)="saveFile()">حفظ التعديلات</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="bsModalRef.hide()">close</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="getURLDowload()">download </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the .css code

```
.modal{
  z-index:1000 !important;
}

.modal-backdrop{
  z-index:999 !important;
}

[dir='rtl'] .modal-title{
  color: rgb(255, 82, 82);
  //font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important;
  margin-right: 20px !important;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.bsm-modal .bsm-modal-x-btn {
  top: 8px;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  right: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 1;
  text-shadow: none;
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: inherit;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
}


.modal-lg {
  max-width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
}
.modal-dialog .gray .modal-lg > .modal-content{
  height:100%
}
.modal-dialog > .modal-content {
  height: 720px;
  width: 100%;
}



.modal-dialog.modal-800 {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}


.modal-footer button {
  width: 10%;
  margin: 1%;
  padding: 0.5% 1%;
}
```

the code to open the modal :

```
 openModalWithComponent() {
    const initialState = {
      list: [
        'Open a modal with component',
        'Pass your data',
        'Do something else',
        '...'
      ],
      title: 'Document Viewer'
    };
    this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(ModalComponent, Object.assign({ initialState }, { class: 'gray modal-lg' }));
    this.bsModalRef.content.closeBtnName = 'Close';
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your modal is using this style, which prevents it from reducing its width, and therefore its content width as well:

```
.modal-dialog.modal-800 {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}
```

Also, notice that the margins set in that same declaration are forcing the PSPDFKit viewer content from taking 100% of the width of the container.

Feel free to [contact support at PSPDFKit](https://support.pspdfkit.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) for any further questions, we're there to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use breaking points in the CSS of the ModalComponent

Example:

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {}

@media only screen and (min-width: 640px) {}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {}